# Bundle a typescript library to one .js file and one .d.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, tsify

I'm developing a library to use in the webbrowser using TypeScript.

I'm writing separate typescript files as modules using "system" as --module, for example this is the main file:

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/simple-html-tokenizer/simple-html-tokenizer" />

export * from "./Decorators/Component";
export * from "./Decorators/Directive";
export * from "./Decorators/Inject";
export * from "./Decorators/Injectable";
export * from "./Events/EventEmitter";
export * from "./Core/Bootstrap";
export * from "./Decorators/Output";
export * from "./Decorators/Input";
export {OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "./Core/LifeCycle/LifeCycleHooks";
```

And this is the first module:

```typescript
import {serviceNormalize} from "../Utils/AngularHelpers";

export interface IComponentMetadata {
    template?: string;
    templateUrl?: string;
    selector?: string;
    directives?: Function[];
    outputs?: string[];
    inputs?: string[];
    styles?: string[];
    providers?: (Function|string)[];
}

/**
 * Register metadata into class to be used by bootstrap.
 */
export function Component(componentMetadata: IComponentMetadata) {
    return (target: any) => {

        /// ...
        /// ...
        /// ...

        return target;
    }
}
```

Well, I'm building it using `gulp-typescript`, I transpile it to `es5` and create one .js and one .d.ts file per each .ts file. So far so good, I have a npm package and I can use my project from other npm projects. But ...

I want to use it from the webbrowser too. I would like to bundle all .js files in one and use this way:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Ng2Emulation-bundle.js"></script>
```

I have generated a .d.ts file using [dts-bundle](https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle) and I have tried to bundle the .js files from two ways:

1. Using concat:

   `gulp.src('dist/js/src/**/*.js')
       .pipe(concat('Ng2Emulation-bundle.js'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/release'));`
2. Using tsify:

   `browserify()
       .add('src/ng2emulation.ts')
       .plugin(tsify, { noImplicitAny: false })
       .bundle()
       .on('error', function (error) { console.error(error.toString()); })
       .pipe(gulp.dest("Ng2Emulation-bundle.js"));`

Two ways create the bundle but when I try to use it from the browser it tries to load each module, getting errors like:

```
GET http://localhost:55411/Utils/AngularHelpers.js 404 (Not Found)D @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4V @ system.js:5t.metadata.deps @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5n @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:4
system.js:4 GET http://localhost:55411/Templates/HttpInterceptor.js 404 (Not Found)D @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4V @ system.js:5t.metadata.deps @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5n @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:4
system.js:4 GET http://localhost:55411/Directives/NgProperty.js 404 (Not Found)D @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4(anonymous function) @ system.js:4V @ system.js:5t.metadata.deps @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5n @ system.js:5r @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:5(anonymous function) @ system.js:4
system.js:4 GET http://localhost:55411/Templates/HtmlParser/Parser.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, an MVC ASP.NET application. My main html (_layout.cshtml) is like it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="~/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.15/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // set our baseURL reference path
        System.config({
            baseURL: '/TypeScript',
            map: {
                "HTML5Tokenizer": "/Scripts/simple-html-tokenizer.js",
                "Ng2Emulation": "/Scripts/Ng2Emulation-es5.js"
            }
        });
        System.defaultJSExtensions = true;

        System.import('App/Boot');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my `App/Boot.ts`:

```typescript
import {bootstrap, Component} from "Ng2Emulation";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>"
})
export class AppComponent { }

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I have tried to load the bundle via: `<script src="~/Scripts/Ng2Emulation-bundle.js"></script>` and remove the `Ng2Emulation` map from `system.config` but I don't have luck :(

I think that there is something that I don't understand in the bundle creation process or in the modules behaivor ...

How to bundle it?
How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, after deep search I have found one way.
I have found [systemjs builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) project.
I have wrote a task in my gulp file, this way:

```javascript
gulp.task("system-builder", function () {
    var builder = new Builder('dist/js/src');

    builder.config({
        meta: {
            'HTML5Tokenizer.js': { // HTML5Tokenizer is a external módule
                build: false       // Not to include in a bundle.
            }
        },
        defaultJSExtensions: true
    });

    builder
        .bundle('Ng2Emulation.js', 'dist/release/Ng2Emulation-bundle.js')
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Build complete');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

I have found it looking at Angular2 gulp files :D
Now I can include the file using html `script` tag, my html is like that:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/simple-html-tokenizer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.15/system.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set our baseURL reference path
    System.config({
        baseURL: '/TypeScript',
        map: {
            "HTML5Tokenizer": "/Scripts/simple-html-tokenizer.js"
        }
    });
    System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Ng2Emulation-es5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    System.import('App/Boot');
</script>
```

It works like a charm.

Still, if anyone knows other ways to do I would like to know.
I don't understand what mudule system is better, when use one or other, ...